# input box issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to assign several rows height quickly, so I've written the below code, however, I don't know why it gives the "Object Required Error".
I actually, don't understand what's this erro?!
please help.

```
Sub RowHeight()
'
' RowHeight
' To assign row height for several choosen rows
'

'
'Variables Declaration
      
      Dim InputBAns As Range                   'Input Box to select the required Rows
      Dim InputH As Long
'User to determine the Range where he requires certain row height
    On Error GoTo Leave:
    Set InputBAns = Application.InputBox("Please select the Rows which you want to apply the Row Height for", "Required Rows", , , , , , 8)
    Set InputH = Application.InputBox("Please determine the required rows height", "Required Rows Height", , 20, , , , 1)
   InputBAns.RowHeight = InputH
Leave:

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set InputH` shouldn't have the `Set` since `InputH` isn't an object.

Comment: It doesn't see "InputH" as an object, so I changed "Set" to be Let, & it worked. But I still don't know why it's on contrarely sees "InputBAns" as an Object

Comment: It's because of the `Type` you set for the `InputBox`. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox ... when `Type=8`, it says `InputBox` will return "a cell reference, as a Range object", vs. when `Type=1` it will return "a number" which is not an Object.